# Is there a way to store a function in a list or dictionary so that when the index (or key) is called it fires off the stored function?

Tags: python, dictionary, dispatch

For instance, I've tried things like this, which doesn't work:

```
mydict = {
    'funcList1': [foo(), bar(), goo()],
    'funcList2': [foo(), goo(), bar()]}
```

Is there some kind of structure with this kind of functionality?

I realize that I could obviously do this just as easily with a bunch of `def` statements:

```
def func1():
    foo()
    bar()
    goo()
```

But the number of statements I need is getting pretty unwieldy and tough to remember. It would be nice to wrap them nicely in a dictionary that I could examine the keys of now and again.

Comment: You've described functional programming without realising it :P

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Functions are first class objects in Python and so you can dispatch using a dictionary. For example, if `foo` and `bar` are functions, and `dispatcher` is a dictionary like so.

```
dispatcher = {'foo': foo, 'bar': bar}
```

Note that the values are `foo` and `bar` which are the function objects, and NOT `foo()` and `bar()`.

To call `foo`, you can just do `dispatcher['foo']()`

EDIT: If you want to run *multiple* functions stored in a list, you can possibly do something like this.

```
dispatcher = {'foobar': [foo, bar], 'bazcat': [baz, cat]}

def fire_all(func_list):
    for f in func_list:
        f()

fire_all(dispatcher['foobar'])
```

Comment: Neat! Can I store multiple function in the value? So when I call the key `[foo]()` it runs all of the functions stored in the value?

Comment: @Zack Added details about multiple functions in a list

Comment: How would this work in the methods were part of a class?

So, if  the function was ``` def func1(self) ``` and when we call this it has to be self.func1, how could we make the "dispatcher" dict?

Comment: Just pass in the method into the dictionary

Comment: @PraveenGollakota Is there a way to store the arguments to the function in the dictionary? I can't seem to figure out how to make that work.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for functions that are defined as part of some other module? Something like sum() from pandas

Comment: Can anyone show you to implement it inside a Class?

Answer (score 1):

### Manipulating functions

In Python, **functions are "first-class objects"** - this means, roughly, that they can be used for every non-type-specific purpose that any other object can be used for. In particular, they can:

- be assigned to names with `=` (and, in fact, the `def` statement *is a form of assignment*)
- be passed as arguments to (other) functions
- be `return`ed from a function
- have attributes which can be inspected with the `.` syntax (in fact, Python allows modifying some of these attributes and assigning new ones; of course this is not possible for all objects)
- participate in expressions (a call to a function *is an expression*; the function-call syntax is conceptually an operator acting upon the function)
- most importantly for current purposes: be stored in other container objects such as lists and dictionaries

The **problem** with the failed attempts described in the question is that they **call the function immediately**. Just like with any other object, [Python code can refer to a function (*itself*, as an object) by its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785933). The name of a function *does not include* parentheses; writing `foo()` means to *call the function now*, and evaluates to *the result* (whatever was `return`ed).

### Example

```
# Set up some demo functions
def foo():
    print('foo function')

def bar():
    print('bar function')

def goo():
    print('goo function')

# Put them into containers
function_sequence = [foo, bar, goo]
function_mapping = {'foo': foo, 'bar': bar, 'goo': goo}

# Access them iteratively
for f in function_sequence:
    # Each time through the loop, a different function is bound to `f`.
    # `f` is thus a name for that function, which can be used to call it.
    f()

# Access one by lookup, and call it.
# The lookup gives us an object which is a function;
# therefore it can be called with the function-call syntax
to_call = input('which function should i call?')
function_mapping[to_call]()
```

The functions themselves are called `foo`, `bar`, and `goo`; and with these names they can be manipulated just like anything else that has a name. There is **nothing special** about writing `foo()` that requires it to use the name from the `def` statement. There is **no requirement to use a name at all**, either - *just as there wouldn't be for e.g. a multiplication*, which could use values looked up from a container, literal values, or values computed from another expression.

As long as there is an expression that evaluates to a function object, that can be a sub-expression of a function-call expression.

### Extensions

#### `lambda`

Python's `lambda` syntax creates objects of the same type as ordinary functions. The syntax restricts what the resulting function can do, and they get a special `__name__` attribute (since there was no `def` statement to specify one during compilation); but otherwise they are perfectly ordinary functions that can be manipulated the same way.

```
def example_func():
    pass

# A list containing two do-nothing functions, created with `def` and `lambda`.
dummies = [example_func, lambda: None]

# Either is usable by lookup:
dummies[0]()
dummies[1]()

# They have exactly the same type:
assert(type(dummies[0]) is type(dummies[1]))
```

#### Instance methods

In Python 3.x, looking up an instance method directly in the class results in a perfectly ordinary function - there is no separate type for ["unbound methods"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949808). When that function is called, an instance must be provided explicitly:

```
class Example:
    def method(self):
        pass

instance = Example()
# Explicit syntax for a method call via the class:
Example.method(instance)
# Following all the same patterns as before, that can be separated:
m = Example.method # the function itself
m(instance) # call it
# Again, `type(m)` is the same function type.
```

Looking up an instance method on an instance, of course, results in a bound method.

```
# Calling a method via the instance:
instance.method()
# This, too, is separable:
bound = instance.method
bound()
```

Bound methods have a different type, but offer the same [callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234) interface as functions: they are called with the `()` syntax.

### `@staticmethod` and `@classmethod`

There is nothing too unexpected here, either:

```
class Fancy:
    @staticmethod
    def s(a, b, c):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def c(cls):
        pass

f = Fancy()
# For both of these, the result is the same whether lookup
# uses the class or the instance.
assert f.s is Fancy.s
# That assertion will NOT work for the classmethod, because method binding
# creates a new bound method object each time.
# But they can be verified to be functionally identical:
assert type(f.c) is type(Fancy.c)
assert f.c.__code__ is Fancy.c.__code__ # etc.

# As before, the results can be stored and used.
# As one would expect, the `cls` argument is bound for the classmethod,
# while the staticmethod expects all arguments that are listed.
fs = f.s
fs(1, 2, 3)
fc = f.c
fc()
```

#### Dealing with arguments

Code that tries to look up a callable (whether it's a function, lambda, bound method, class...) from some data structure and then call it, will need to be able to supply appropriate arguments for the call. Of course, this is easiest to arrange if every available callable expects the same number of arguments (with the same types and semantics). In many cases it's necessary to adapt such callables by pre-filling arguments that won't come from the common arguments supplied by lookup, or by wrapping them to ignore arguments.

```
def zero():
    pass

def one(a):
    print('a', a)

def two(a, b):
    print('a', a, 'b', b)

funcs = # help!

def dispatch():
    a = input('what should be the value of a?')
    f = input('which func should be used?')
    return funcs[f](a)
```

Ignoring arguments can be done by writing an explicit wrapper, or by redesigning so that keyword arguments will be passed instead (and [having the called function simply ignore any extraneous `**kwargs` contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515595)).

See [How can I bind arguments to a function in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277922) for the case of pre-filling arguments.

For example, we could adapt using lambdas (this gets unwieldy with large numbers of parameters):

```
funcs = {
    'zero': (lambda a: zero()),
    'one': one,
    'two': (lambda a: two(a, 'bee'))
}
```

Or redesign the underlying functions to make them more usable in this setup first:

```
from functools import partial

def zero(**kwargs):
    pass

def one(a):
    print('a', a)

def two(b, a): # this order is more convenient for functools.partial
    print('a', a, 'b', b)

funcs = {'zero': zero, 'one': one, 'two': partial(two, 'bee')}

def dispatch():
    a = input('what should be the value of a?')
    f = input('which func should be used?')
    return funcs[f](a=a)
```

`functools.partial` is particularly useful here, as it avoids a [common trap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431676) caused by *late binding* in lambdas. For example, if the adapter `lambda a: two(a, 'bee')` used a variable instead of the literal `'bee'` text, and that variable subsequently changed, the change *would be reflected* when using the `dispatch` function (this is usually not desired).

Answer (score 0):

```
# Lets say you have 10 programs or functions:
func_list = [program_001, program_002, program_003, program_004, program_005,
             program_006, program_007, program_008, program_009, program_010]

choose_program = int(input('Please Choose a program: ')) # input function number

func_list[choose_program - 1]()
```