# How to loop function inside itself and execute some of them if function name contains specific string

Tags: python

I have a script define many functions. Now I want to execute some of them in a batch.

eg:

```
def foo_fun1():
   xxx

def foo_fun2():
   xxx

...

def bar_funx():
   yyy
```

I now want to loop all function and pickup some of them if the function name contains "foo", how to archive that ?

```
for fun in dir():
    if 'foo' in fun:
         #
         # the fun is string
         # how to call the string as function here??
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could try `globals()[fun]()` to call the function, with no arguments.

Comment: but how about if I need arguments?  fun(arg1,arg2)

Comment: @TomKarzes It's better to avoid using `globals()` unless you have no other choice, and generally there are better choices.

Comment: You could put your functions into a dict, with the function name as the key. Also, a function stores its name as an attribute. In your loop you can do `name = fun.__name__`

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, it's not how I would do it, but I was directly addressing what OP was asking.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205081/is-there-a-way-to-store-a-function-in-a-list-or-dictionary-so-that-when-the-inde and the linked questions there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `globals()` function, which returns a `dict` of every global object

```py
def say_hey():
    print('hey')

def say_hi():
    print('hi')

def main():
    for name, func in globals().items():
        if 'say_' in name and callable(func):
            func()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

which outputs

```
hey
hi
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals