# Can you make a switch-case-type list without conditions in Python where it just chooses a random case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, switch-statement

This is a question that is just about convenience (/laziness) of writing. I know I will spend more time writing this question than how much I will save, but I'm curious. EDIT: I am aware that it might not be possible to do what I'm looking for, but I was curious to see if someone with more knowledge of Python knew of a way. I've also edited my codeblocks to clarify some situations that came up in the comments.

Say I have 3 things that can happen, and my program is supposed to choose one at random. Now I'm going to add a 4th thing that can happen, but I don't want to have to increase the `b` in `random.randint(a,b)`, nor do I want to have to increase the `i` in `elif Case == i:`

Right now I have this:

```
x_1 = 0
x_2 = 0
Case = random.randint(1, 3)

if Case == 1: ## a, b, and d are known
    mylist = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
    x_1 += 1
        
elif Case == 2: ## a, b, and f are known
    mylist = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
    x_2 += 1
        
elif Case == 3: ## a, c, and d are known
    mylist = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
    x_1 += 2
    x_2 += x_1
```

Then, if I want to add a 4th case, I copy-paste one, and just edit the body of the case. However, I also need to change the `3` in the first line, as well as the `3` in the line I just pasted. And, **the important part**, if I want to add an option between Case 1 and Case 2 for readability, it means I have to update all the integers after my new Case 2 - which is the thing that I don't want to have to do.

Is there a way where Python could pick one of my elifs at random? Obviously they don't have to be elifs, I tried looking at switch-cases also, but haven't found what I'm looking for. Something like this:

```
ChooseRandomOption
    option ## a, b, and d are known
        mylist = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
        x_1 += 1

    option ## a, b, and f are known
        mylist = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
        x_2 += 1

    option ## a, c, and d are known
        mylist = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
        x_1 += 2
        x_2 += x_1
```

and then all I have to do is add this and not change anything else:

```
    option ## a, b, and e are known
        mylist = [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
        x_1 -= 1
```

Thanks!

PS.

1. Keep in mind, the purpose is to write even less, so adding functions and picking a random function is not really what I'm looking for. EDIT: Especially since the inputs to each function could be different.
2. (EDIT: This PS has now been integrated in the codeblocks) The list is just one example of what could be done, but maybe multiple actions have to be executed inside the `option`, so `mylist = random.choice([[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]])` may work here, but not in other cases. I would also still like to add a comment in each case to clarify what situation it is.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by _"the important part, if I want to add an option between Case 1 and Case 2..."_? Also how do you expect to perform multiple actions (and what would these actions be) without defining a function? Defining a bunch of functions and picking (and calling) a random one seems to be the solution to me here. Can you explain why this is unacceptable?

Comment: Your PS seems to be ruling out all the common ways to achieve what you want without a bunch of `if` statements.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I edited the last code block slightly to showcase it more clearly what I mean by that. For readability I would place this 4th option between the first and the second option: (a, b, d) -> (a, b, e) -> (a, b, f).

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Inside my elif I could write multiple actions, like `X_1 = 5; X_2 = 3; print(X_1); mylist.append(X_2)`, I don't know, just anything. The thing is, I'm curious if there is any way that what I'm asking could be done or not. I know the functions are one way, but then it would be shorter to just keep the elifs that I already have.

Comment: @Barmar Unfortunately that's what I think so too, hence why I came here to see if other people with more Python knowledge than me would have any idea.

Comment: If there's no pattern to the actions that can be in each `if/elif` block, the best you can do is a list of functions. If there's morein common among the actions, you can use lists of data.

Comment: "but maybe multiple actions have to be executed inside the option" You mean that, rather than simply determining a *value* that could be assigned to a variable, you want to run some *code* that is chosen randomly?

Comment: If you really don't want to use functions or create a data structure, I don't think there's anything that can be done here, sorry. `if``/`elif` gets evaluated sequentially, and each one needs to have a condition, which will have to be different for each case. The cases could choose a random value in-line, but because they're evaluated sequentially, the probability has to be different for each. `match`/`case` will have the same problems.

Comment: FWIW, an existing question for the function-based technique: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205081

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes any case can have any code. I think you're right that unfortunately there is no way to do this with less writing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a list of functions, then execute a random one. That way you can even have random behaviour, not just lists, and can name them for clarity as well.

```
def func1():
    return [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]

def func2():
    return [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]

def func3():
    return [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]

myFuncs = [func1, func2, func3]
myFunc = random.choice(myFuncs)
myList = myFunc()
```

If you really, really don't ever want to update the myFuncs list, you could do something like this and prefix your function names with an identifier

```
import inspect
import sys

def listFunc1():
    return [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]

def listFunc2():
    return [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]

def func3():
    return [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]

myFuncs = [obj for name,obj in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__]) 
                                  if (inspect.isfunction(obj) 
                                  and name.startwith('listFunc')]
myFunc = random.choice(myFuncs)
myList = myFunc()
```

Comment: While I agree that this is the best way of doing what OP wants, they seem to have rejected this approach (see their P.S. 1)

Comment: Appreciate the attempt! However, as said the functions are more work than just keeping the `elif`s. Maybe one `elif` changes the value of some `X_1` while the second `elif` changes the value of some `X_2` and `X_3`.

Comment: I have marked this as correct, as an `if/elif` list is as short as it seems to get, and I appreciate the tip of getting all the functions inside the module that match a certain name structure.

Comment: If the functions go in a separate, dedicated module, then `inspect` isn't necessary - the functions will just be attributes of the `module` object, which can easily be enumerated via the `__dict__` attribute or `dir` builtin.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
cases = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
}

print(cases.get(random.choice(list(cases.keys()))))
```

Using a dict to store your cases allows you to pick a random entry from the dict by randomly choosing from the keys of the dictionary. You can easily add more entries or remove them at will.

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same as the list of lists in their 2nd PS? How does putting it in a dictionary improve?