# Introspection to Determine Originally Bound Variable of an Instance

Tags: python

Is there anyway to determine the variable to which an instance was originally bound?

With a function we can do this:

```
def f():
    pass
print f.__name__
>> f
g = f
print g.__name__
>> f
```

What I want is:

```
class c:
    pass

mything = c()
print mything.__name__
>> mything
```

The reason I want this is for more intuitive logging/error messages for an API I'm writing.. I.e. it would be nice to have

```
print mything
>> instance of c originally bound to 'mything'
```

Instead of the usual:

```
print mything
>> <__main__.c instance at 0x7fb7994b25a8>
```

And (I think?) would be nice to not make people explicitly supply a `__name__` attribute in `__init__` all the time..

Is this possible? advisable?

Comment: Even if this were possible, how would you handle `[c() for _ in range(1000000)]`? That is 1 million instances of `c` that have no name bound at all..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the name of an object in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538342/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-an-object-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want for example something like this (the function example confuses me):

```
class Foo(object):
    # something here
    pass

a = Foo()
b = Foo()
c = Foo()

print a.__name # a
print b.__name # b
print c.__name # c
```

? if so, no that is not possible. This information cannot be carried within the instance. Many Instance can point to the same instance like here:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     pass
...
>>>
>>> a = Foo()
>>> b = a
>>> c = b
>>>
>>> print a
<__main__.Foo object at 0x01765B70>
>>> print b
<__main__.Foo object at 0x01765B70>
>>> print c
<__main__.Foo object at 0x01765B70>
>>>
```

They all the same, which instance name to carry, go the point? another issue is here:

```
class Foo(object):
    pass

a = [Foo(), Foo(), Foo()]
```

The only possible solution I can think of is to tag the instance on initialization:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self.__name__ = name
...
>>> a = Foo('a')
>>> b = Foo('b')
>>> c = Foo('c')
>>>
>>> a.__name__
'a'
>>> b.__name__
'b'
>>> c.__name__
'c'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way, and if there were a way, it wouldn't be as useful as you think. When you define a function, you give it a name, and most references to the function will use the name. On the other hand, other objects tend not to be tied as tightly to a single name.

```
def factory_function(parameter):
    obj = Thing(parameter)
    obj.preprocess_somehow()
    return obj

game_window = factory_function(parameter)
menu_screen = factory_function(parameter)
subscreens = [factory_function(parameter) for parameter in params]
```

The most interesting names for the objects here are `game_window`, `menu_screen`, and `subscreens`, but the "first variable" `game_window` and `menu_screen` are bound to is either `obj` or something earlier, perhaps `self` or some C-level variable in an allocator function. The items of `subscreens` don't even have useful individual names.

Comment: That's a good point, I agree with you. Can you expand on why it is not possible though? I'm kind of just curious now about how such a thing would even work (or not work)..

Comment: @qwwqwwq: The function definition syntax requires that a function be assigned a canonical name when created, but general objects don't have that. It'd be way too verbose to have to name every single list, dict, heck, every single integer in your program. When you write `x = 1 + 1`, can you imagine what it'd be like if you had to give the `1`s a name? You *could* do it if you really wanted to design a language that way, but no one would use it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hackish way I found to do this, for posterity's sake:

```
def find_global_var_name( target_obj ):
    for name, obj in globals().iteritems():
        if id(obj) == id(target_object):
            return name
```

Assumes a globally defined variable, which is in line with my usecase, I'm not going to use it though since sentiment seems overwhelmingly negative about this whole thing..