# Print variable names when looping over a list

Tags: python

Consider the list of variables and a Python list:

```
apple='green'
banana='yellow'
orange='orange'

fruits = [apple, banana, orange]
```

How to print the names of variables, instead of its values when lopping over the elements of the list?

```
for fruit in fruits:
    #print the names of variables, that is "apple", "banana", etc.
```

I know that a dictionary would be a better fit in this problem but for the sake of argument, is it possible to do it with a list?

Comment: Possible, if you can guarantee that no other variables have the same value. Not something you'd want to rely on, though. See [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals).

Comment: At first glance, you could probably do something with either `vars()` or `globals()`. However, you’d have to loop over and see which variable names have the value you’re checking. This will be a problem if 2 variables have the same value. As you describe, a `dict` is the best solution here.

Comment: The list doesn't hold the variables; it just holds their values. Use a dict instead.

Comment: A dictionary would definitely be better. See [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/4518341)

Answer (score 2):

You want this:

```
apple = "green"
banana = "yellow"
orange = "orange"

fruits = [apple, banana, orange]
for fruit in fruits:
    fruit_name = [key for key, value in locals().items() if value == fruit]
    print(fruit_name[0])
```

Answer (score -1):

It is a bit of a cheat, but if you store the names of the variables in the fruits array instead of the variable itself, it is trivial:

```
>>> apple = 'green'
>>> banana = 'yellow'
>>> orange = 'orange'
>>> fruits = ['apple','banana','orange']
>>> for fruit in fruits:
...     print fruit, vars()[fruit]
...     
apple green
banana yellow
orange orange
```

If you are really wanting to get the variable name, you have a problem as the array is not storing the variable, but the string it is pointing at - for example, you can change the content of apple after the assignment to demonstrate the array holds the original string:

```
>>> fruity = [ apple, orange, banana ]
>>> apple = 'yikes'
>>> print fruity
['green', 'orange', 'yellow']
```

The best you can do is build a reverse lookup of the vars() dictionary and attempt to look up the variable...

```
>>> yy = dict([v,k] for k,v in vars().items() if isinstance(v,str))
>>> for fruit in fruity:
...     print yy.get(fruit,'Unknown'), fruit
...     
Unknown green
orange orange
banana yellow
```

Comment: that's pretty much the opposite of what the question asked for.. it double defines the vars and the var names (separately, redundantly), instead of accessing the name of the var. and then repeats the original question, pointing out that "you have a problem"

Comment: Thank you @KingOtto for that observation -- as this was clearly a "discussion expected" suggested approach, I look forward to seeing your solution.

Answer (score -2):

use NamedObject, that should work:

```
apple='green'
banana='yellow'
orange='orange'
fruits = [apple, banana, orange]    

apple = NamedObject('apple', apple)
print(apple)
print(apple.name)
```

this should print:

```
green
apple
```

If you dont understand, here is another similar thing: [Access the name of a list in a Python print statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42007655/access-the-name-of-a-list-in-a-python-print-statement)

Comment: In this case, why don't you create a dictionary containing all the fruits ?

Comment: that's pretty much the opposite of what the question asked for.. it double defines the vars and the var names (separately, redundantly), instead of accessing the name of the var.