# Get names of *args in a python method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not sure if it is possible. But suppose I have some python class with constructor as follows:

```
class SomeClass(object):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        pass
        # here I want to iterate over args
        # get name of each arg
```

Suppose I use this class somewhere and create an instance of it:

```
some_var = SomeClass(user, person, client, doctor)
```

What I mean by get name of arg, is to get names ('user', 'person', 'client' and 'doctor')

I really mean just get string name of a argument. Where user, person etc. are some python objects with their attributes etc, but I only need the name of how these variables (objects) are named.

Comment: Then why not just pass in a string? `SomeClass("user", "person", "client", "doctor")`?

Comment: You can use kwargs for this

Comment: @Sweeper, no I mean those args are objects, they just named as 'user' etc

Comment: @ArpitSolanki, yes I know, but I am wondering if it is possible to do without kwargs.

Comment: So you can't change the calling code?

Comment: @Sweeper, when you declare an instance of some class, you name it, right. Then you may pass it to some method (ex user, person). I want to get this name as string. The name of variable.

Comment: You can user "__str__" for getting the name of object

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538342/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-an-object-in-python

Answer (score 4):

- `*args` should be used when you are unsure how many arguments will be passed to your function
- `**kwargs` lets you to handle named arguments that you have not defined in advance (kwargs = keyword arguments)

So `**kwargs` is a dictionary added to the parameters.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists

Answer (score 0):

Use `**kwargs` and `setattr` like this:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

and you'll get access to the keywords and the values as well, no matter which type they are.