# Create column names of DataFrame based on variable name

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Is there a method to create column names based on the input variables in a Dataframe? Currently I am manually adjusting the column names whenever I make a change to the input variable. It would benefit me to only do this step once.

An example would be:

```
data = []
data1 = [1, 2, 3]
data2 = [3, 4, 5]
data3 = [6, 'a', 12]
combined = [data1, data2, data3]
data.append = (combined)

df = pd.Dataframe(data, columns = combined)
```

Desired result:

|  | data1 | data2 | data3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 3 | 6 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | a |
| 2 | 3 | 5 | 12 |

Comment: You can define variables as key-value pairs inside a dictionary, this way you can keep track of all the variables more efficiently plus creating a dataframe from such dictionary is very straightforward task.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is python doesn't have an in built function for turning the name of your variable into a string.

A [previous question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16139159/5851885) about getting names offers a function for enquiring through global objects to find the name of a given variable.
Alternatively you can just write a list of strings containing the names (see commented-out lines).

```py
data1 = [1, 2, 3]
data2 = [3, 4, 5]
data3 = [6, 'a', 12]
combined = [data1, data2, data3]
# column_names = ["data1", "data2", "data3"] 

def name_of_global_obj(xx):
    for objname, oid in globals().items():
        if oid is xx:
            return objname

df = pd.DataFrame({name_of_global_obj(data_i) : data_i for data_i in combined})
# df = pd.DataFrame({name : data_i for name, data in zip(column_names,combined)})
```