# Printing Object Names

Tags: python, object, names

I am slowly moving ahead with my python journey. I wanted to ask the following regarding Object Orientation.

Question 1)

I have created a class called human which when instantiated requires the attributes sex, eye color, height.

I have created 2 x methods one which calculates the age and one method that just prints all the objects attributes to the screen.

```
from datetime import date
 
class human():
 
     
    def __init__(self, sex, eyecolor, height, yearborn):
        self.sex = sex
        self.eyecolor = eyecolor
        self.height = height
        self.yearborn = yearborn
         
        print(self.sex, self.eyecolor, self.height, self.yearborn)
         
         
    def age(self):
        currentdate = date.today()
        a = currentdate.year - self.yearborn
        return a
     
     
     
    def display(self):
        print(self.sex)
        print(self.eyecolor)
        print(self.height)
        print(self.yearborn)
```

When I create an object I use the following code:-

```
import humanclass
Tom = humanclass.human("Male","Green", 173, 1994)
```

I get the following output:-

```
Male Green 173 1994
```

My question is this, is there anyway I can include the name of the object in the def **init** function so that when python prints the attributes out using the code:-

```
print(self.sex, self.eyecolor, self.height, self.yearborn)
```

whatever the user called the object name is also printed out in this case Tom?

Thank you.

Comment: In Python, __repr__ is a special method used to represent a class's objects as a string. ... According to the official documentation, __repr__ is used to compute the “official” string representation of an object and is typically used for debugging

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the name of an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538342/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-an-object-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

No.

Tom is a variable name and has nothing to do with your `human` object, other than holds a reference for it.
If you want the object to know that it is Tom, add a `name` (or similar) input for it.

As a side note, you should use the `def __str__(self):` method to your class that will return the string you want to show when you "print" your object (instead of your `display` method)

Comment: `def __str__(self):`?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary. Below I provided an example of how this can be done

```
class Shape:
    def __init__(self,sides):
        self.sides = sides
    def display(self,name):
        return self.sides,name
objs = {"square":Shape(4)}
print(objs["square"].display("squares"))
```