# How to get the name of a nested list?

Tags: python, list

I'm wondering if something like this is possible. Let's suppose this snippet of code:

```
area = ["A","B","C"]
level = ["L1","L2","L3"]

sector = [area, level]

print(sector)

print(sector[1])
```

Output:

- Print 1: `[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['L1', 'L2', 'L3']]`
- Print 2: `['L1', 'L2', 'L3']`

The first print is OK for me. It shows the lists and their elements.

However, for the second print I would like to have **the name of the list** instead of its elements. In this case **level**

Is that possible?

Comment: What would be *the name of the list*?

Comment: No, that's not possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538342/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-an-object

Comment: I don't think this is really useful to even get in the first place, If you want to map some variables to a "name" I would look into using dictionaries

Comment: A name is just a name for an object. The object doesn't know and can have multiple names. The list contains objects which may or may not also have names elsewhere. Why do you need this?

Comment: @mkrieger1 - Unfortunately there are even [packages](https://pypi.org/project/varname) for this.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny How on earth would you maintain code written like with that package?

Comment: You don't understand how names and values work in Python. See [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: Thanks all of you for your help. As I said I'm new with python. I did not about dictionary. It is very useful. This was a requirement from client and wanted to be sure about this before answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it into a Dictionary of Lists instead of a List of Lists:

```
area = ["A","B","C"]
level = ["L1","L2","L3"]

sectors = {
    "area":  area,
    "level": level
}

print(sectors["level"])
print(sectors["area"])

""" some other useful dict methods below """

print(sectors.keys())
print(sectors.values())
print(sectors.items())
```

Comment: Thanks Joe. Your example was very useful. I've learn something new about Python.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do though, is use a dictionnary:

```
di = {"area": ["A", "B", "C"], "level": ["L1", "L2", "L3"]}

di["area"]
```

Output :

```
["A", "B", "C"]
```

Comment: Thanks Odhian. As I said, I'm new in Python, I was not aware about this structure. Very useful

Answer (score 2):

You could compare the `id`:

```
for sec in sector:
    if id(sec) == id(area):
        print('area')
    elif id(sec) == id(level):
        print('level')
```

etc.

However, this is a dubious way to go. Why do you need this?

Comment: It was a requirement from the client. But given that my knowledge is limited right now I want to be sure before answering. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would question why the client needs this. It's not easily supported in Python, and really suggests it's ill-conceived. See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary for your usecase.

You can make the name of the variables as key and lists as values.

Try this:

```
area = ["A","B","C"]
level = ["L1","L2","L3"]

sector = {"area":area, "level":level}

print(list(sector.values()))

print(list(sector.keys()))
```

Outputs:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['L1', 'L2', 'L3']]

['area', 'level']
```

Comment: Thanks Prashant. As I said, I'm new in Python, I was not aware about this structure. Very useful